# Wonders whether there's some principled way to define classes with getter/setter with less boilerplate

Tags: python

In Python world, IIUC, you generally have two kinds of options, every attribute is constant and frozen, like namedtuple, vs every attribute is modifiable.

You can write lots of `getter/setter` with `@property`. However, it's lots of boilerplates.

I like approaches like class `Child(namedtuple(...))`, however, it has the following downsides:

1. If in the inheritance you set `__slots__ = ()`, then you can't add additional attribute into the child class.
2. If you don't set `__slots__`, then you can add additional attribute, however, there's no protection on assigning wrong attribute `child.some_non_exist = some_value`
3. Moreover, there's no way to optionally allow some attribute to be accessible and some attribute not.

I can have the following proposal, however, I don't know whether there's existing library for this.

Thanks!!

(I know attrs but I think it's focusing another set of problems.)

```
### The following is a proposal

@attr_acl
class A(object):
   x = attr_acl.frozen()    # x must be specified in __init__
   y = attr_acl.frozen(default = 5) 
   z = attr_acl.mutable(default = 5)
   zz = attr_acl.mutable_freezable()
   g = attr_acl.mutable(is_final=True)

@attr_acl
class AA(X):
   o = attr_acl.mutable()

aa = AA(x=1, zz=2, o=3)
attr_acl.freeze(obj.zz)

### The followings must raise error
aa.x = 5
aa.zz = 6 
aa.some_non_exist = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look harder at attrs and dataclasses.  They provide what you want:

```
@attr.s(slots=True)
class Coordinates(object):
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()
```

But also you should consider whether you need to protect your attributes.  It's easy to slip into a habit of overly defensive coding, where you work hard to prevent things that are not going to actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rudimentary implementation of the proposal without any dependencies, in case we want to proceed with not using attrs or dataclasses. It's only tested with the sample code in the question.

```
class UnsetDefaultAttributeValue(object):
    pass

class AclAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self._value.__str__()

class FrozenAttribute(AclAttribute):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._init_value_set = False
        self._default_value = kwargs.get('default',
                                         UnsetDefaultAttributeValue())
        self._value = self._default_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self._value is UnsetDefaultAttributeValue and not self._init_value_set:
            raise AttributeError('Value must be specified')
        return self

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if (self._init_value_set):
            raise AttributeError('Attribute is frozen')
        self._value = value
        self._init_value_set = True

class MutableAttribute(AclAttribute):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._init_value_set = False
        self._default_value = kwargs.get('default', None)
        self._is_final = kwargs.get('is_final', False)
        self._value = self._default_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if (self._is_final):
            raise AttributeError('Attribute is finalized')
        self._value = value
        self._init_value_set = True

class MutableFreezableAttribute(AclAttribute):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._init_value_set = False
        self._is_frozen = False
        self._default_value = kwargs.get('default',
                                         UnsetDefaultAttributeValue())
        self._value = self._default_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if (self._is_frozen):
            raise AttributeError('Attribute is frozen')
        self._value = value
        self._init_value_set = True

    def freeze(self):
        self._is_frozen = True

class attr_acl(type):
    def __new__(self, class_definition, *args, **kwargs):
        def _init_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

        def _set_attr(self, key, value):
            if not hasattr(self, key):
                raise AttributeError('Attribute does not exist')
            attr = getattr(self, key)
            attr.__set__(self, value)

        class_definition.__init__ = _init_class
        class_definition.__setattr__ = _set_attr
        return class_definition

    @classmethod
    def frozen(*args, **kwargs):
        default_value = kwargs.get('default', None)
        return FrozenAttribute(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def mutable(*args, **kwargs):
        default_value = kwargs.get('default', None)
        return MutableAttribute(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def mutable_freezable(*args, **kwargs):
        default_value = kwargs.get('default', None)
        return MutableFreezableAttribute(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def freeze(self, attribute):
        attribute.freeze()


### The following is a proposal

@attr_acl
class A(object):
    x = attr_acl.frozen()    # x must be specified in __init__
    y = attr_acl.frozen(default = 5) 
    z = attr_acl.mutable(default = 5)
    zz = attr_acl.mutable_freezable()
    g = attr_acl.mutable(is_final=True)

@attr_acl
class AA(A):
   o = attr_acl.mutable()

aa = AA(x=1, zz=2, o=3)
attr_acl.freeze(aa.zz)

### The followings must raise error
aa.x = 5
aa.zz = 6 
aa.some_non_exist = 7
```